# Analytic functionals carried by $K$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, dual-spaces, limits-colimits

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. By definition, one has $$\mathcal{O}'(K) = \left( \varinjlim_{U\supset K} \mathcal{O}(U) \right)',$$ where $U$ are open neighborhoods of $K$. My question is : Do we have $$\mathcal{O}'(K) \simeq  \varprojlim_{U\supset K} \mathcal{O}'(U) ?$$ (Here, we are considering strong duals.) These things are in general not true for Fréchet spaces but since we work with very particular and nice spaces, I wonder if it could be true.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\mathscr O$ is the sheaf of analytic functions? What topology do you give $\mathscr O(U)$?

Comment: For $K$ a disk, your inclusion should follow from $f(z/(1-\epsilon)) \to f$ in the topology so $ \varprojlim_{U\supset K} \mathcal{O}'(U)$ is dense and it suffices to show it is closed. I would look at $B(U) = \{ f$ analytic and bounded on $U\},\|f\|_{B(U)} = \sup_{z \in U} |f(z)|$ and say a distribution $\in B(U)'$ which is supported on $V \subset U, d(\partial V, \partial U) = r > 0$ can be seen (by the Cauchy integral formula) as a measure supported on a curve at a distance $r/2$ of $\partial V, \partial U$.

Comment: s.harp : Yes the sheaf of holomorphic functions. I give the usual topology of uniform convergence on each compact subset.